# Conditional probability (example)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

> Suppose that the probability of a random traffic light displaying
>   light of a specific color when the previous traffic light is
>   displaying the same color is $p$. The first light is red with
>   probability $a$ and green with probability $1-a$. What's the
>   probability of the third being green?

Let $P(X_n)$ represent the probability that the $n$-th light is displaying the color $X=R$ or $G$.

From hypothesis: 
$$P(R_2|R_1)=P(R_3|R_2)=p$$ 
$$P(R_1)=a$$
 $P(R_3)$ is needed to find $P(G_3)=1-P(R_3)$, but Bayes' theorem gives too many unknowns such as $P(R_1|R_2)$ for example. What's the right approach for this problem?

Comment: Why would you need to know $P(R_1|R_2)$ to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried using Bayes' theorem to appear $P(R_3)$, but ended up with too many unknown probabilities.

Comment: I see. I think rather than trying to use Bayes theorem, just use the definition of conditional probability, $$P(A|B)= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.$$  This will not result in any reversal of the order of events in the conditional probability. Are you familiar with the use of probability trees for problems such as this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are familiar with the notion of a probability tree, but just in case you aren't (or for anyone else reading this), I will include a brief description. If several random variables exist and we know something about their conditional probabilities, we can compute probabilities of events by a tree. In this case, we have three random variables ($C_1$, the color of the first light, $C_2$, the color of the second, $C_3$, the color of the third). We make a probability tree with four levels (where the initial level is just a trivial node, the root node). Since $C_1$ can either be red or green, there are two branches away from the root node onto the nodes $R_1$, $G_1$ on the second level. Traveling down a branch means we are realizing a particular color of the first light.

From each of those nodes, we draw two further branches to two successor nodes ($R_2$ and $G_2$). Traveling down one of those nodes is realizing a color of the second light. Similarly, each node on the third level has two successors ($R_3$ and $G_3$) on the fourth level, corresponding to one of the two values of the third light.

Each possible outcome corresponds to a path from the root node to one of the terminal nodes. The path from the top to the bottom using $R_1, R_2, R_3$ corresponds to the outcome $R_1\cap R_2\cap R_3$. Between the first and second levels of the trees, we put the probabilities of the two event $R_1$ and $G_1$ on the branches. The branch to $R_1$ gets probability $a$ (this is given), and the complement $G_1$ gets $1-a$.

For the other levels of the tree, we label the branch with the conditional probability of the lower node given the upper node. For example, the branch from $R_1$ to $R_2$ is labeled with $P(R_2|R_1)=p$.

For a particular outcome (say $R_1\cap R_2\cap R_3$), we look at the path from the top of the tree to the bottom going through the nodes $R_1, R_2, R_3$ and multiplying the numbers on the branches of the path (which are $a, p,p$). Thus $P(R_1\cap R_2\cap R_3)=ap^2$.

Now in our tree, four of the nodes at the bottom are $G_3$, so we need to find the probability of each and add. These four nodes at the bottom labeled $G_3$ correspond to the four exclusive events $R_1\cap R_2\cap G_3$, $R_1\cap G_2\cap G_3$, $G_1\cap R_2\cap G_3$, $G_1\cap G_2\cap G_3$ (and each event corresponds to the nodes used in a path from the top to the bottom for that event). That is, the first of the four nodes labeled $G_3$ is the end result of the path using the nodes $R_1, R_2$, and $G_3$, and so that corresponds to the outcome $R_1\cap R_2\cap G_3$.

So what we should do is for each of the four nodes labeled $G_3$, take the path from the top to that node and multiply the weights on those branches in the path. For the first node going through the nodes $R_1, R_2, G_3$, the weights on the edges down that path are $a, p, 1-p$, and so $P(R_1\cap R_2\cap G_3)=ap(1-p)$. Do the same thing for the other three nodes labeled $G_3$ and add all the results to get $P(G_3)$. [image]